# Sum value from fields which are in one row

Tags: php, mysql, sum, rows

can someone please tell me how I can to sum 7 fields which are in one row?

I have tabled called invoice, which consists of

```
ID | Name | Money1 | Money2 | Money3 | Money4 | Total |
1  | John | 65.00  | 65.00  | 65.00  | 65.00  |  ???  |
```

How to create like default value for row TOTAL to be Money1 + Money2 + Money3 + Money4??
Or when using mysql query how can I somehow show total?
Something like that..

```
echo "<td>" . $row['money1'] . " + " . $row['money2'] ."</td>"; .......?
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum.

Comment: You can use MySQL's [`SUM()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) aggregate function.

Comment: Whhhhhhhhhyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy? Oh, the humanity. :-(

Comment: and @Fred-ii- no you can't

Comment: @Strawberry This works `SELECT *, sum(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 ) as total` which is what I use in one of my test scripts. Which is much shorter than using `SELECT Name, Money1, Money2, Money3, Money4, (Money1+Money2+Money3+Money4) AS Total`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It works just as well without the SUM() bit!

Comment: @Strawberry No argument there. But saying "no" to `SUM` is not quite correct. It can be used.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, there are lots of functions you can use that will have no effect on the outcome. I don't think it's right to provide them as an answer. I mean, SELECT COALESCE(LOWER(3+5+9)) = 17, so I guess that's an answer too.

Comment: @Strawberry No argument there again. There are many ways to achieve what the OP wishes to get and not just in SQL neither, but in PHP also. Your points are indeed valid and true.

Comment: While it's possible to use the SUM function to sum over all rows, this doesn't seem to be what the OP asked for. Summing up values "from fields which are in **one row**" is done by using an arithmetic expression in a calculated column, e.g. `(col1 + col2 + ...)` AS total.

Comment: Of course you may want to also get the grand total of all the money columns over all rows in the table, in which case you'd do `SUM(col1 + col2 + ...)` AS grand_total : )

Comment: Ok, I've just read a bit in the MySQL docs and it turns out that doing `SELECT *, SUM(Money 1 + Money 2 + ...)`, as Fred -ii suggests above, will work. But this is only because of how MySQL handles GROUP BY. See the second paragraph [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html): "If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows." However, this would be an unnecessary use of an aggregate function, as the intention is not to sum over all rows.

Comment: If you're interested in how aggregate functions work, [the page I mentioned in my last comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in the MySQL docs is a great place to start reading : )

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now, but will edit my answer later on to include some examples of cases where SUM will and will not work. @user2396348: in the meantime I would encourage you to read about the SUM aggregate function and also to simply try out the different solutions that are offered here to get a feel for how the calculations work with your data. Trying/testing is the best way to figure out what works best for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add up the 'Money' columns in a calculated column, in your SQL query:

```
SELECT Name, Money1, Money2, Money3, Money4, (Money1+Money2+Money3+Money4) AS Total
FROM tablename;
```

Then you can show the total value in your PHP code by accessing the calculated column:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>";
```

---

**UPDATE**: Some people suggested in their answers that the SUM aggregate function can be used to solve the OP's problem. This won't always work in general, so I wanted to provide some clarification by giving two examples (based on the OP's table structure): one that works and one that does not work.

### Ex 1: It works when you include the primary key column

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Money1+Money2+Money3+Money4) AS Total
FROM tablename;
```

According to [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), a query with an aggregate function, but without a GROUP BY clause, will behave as if we were grouping on all columns in the SELECT part. This means that, in this case, we are grouping on the ID column, which is an auto-incrementing integer (presumably), and therefore each row in the table is its own group. Now, the SUM function gives us the sum over all rows within each group. Therefore it will give us the SUM of each row in the table, which is what the OP wanted.

**Note:** this also means that using the SUM function is pointless, as we are taking the sum over a single term. Just think of it mathematically:

```
SUM(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4) = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4
```

Remember that MySQL can handle simple mathematical expressions just fine. There's no need to use SUM here : )

### Ex 2: It does NOT work without primary key column

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Money1+Money2+Money3+Money4) AS Total
FROM tablename;
```

This example will **not** give us the per-row totals the OP expects. Once again we're grouping on all rows (as per MySQL manual). So, assuming there are several entries for the name 'John', we will get the money fields of all the rows for 'John' added up and merged into a single result row. Like this:

Let's say we had the following rows...

```
Name         Money1   Money2   Money3   Money4

John             1       2       2       3
John             1       2       2       3
John             1       2       2       3
Simon            2       1       1       1
```

... then the above query would give us this result:

```
Name         Total

John            24
Simon            5
```

Comment: Tried this one and everything works perfectly. Glad I asked here. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You use the `SUM()` [aggregate function in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
 SELECT Name, Money1, Money2, Money3, Money4, SUM(money1 + money2 + money3 + money4) AS total
 FROM table
```

Comment: That wasn't my downvote, but this `SUM(money1, money2, money3, money4)` would need to be `SUM(money1 + money2 + money3 + money4)` in order for it to work. Otherwise, it will throw a `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...` error.

Comment: @Strawberry Not a terribly useful comment. You seem to have something against `SUM` but haven't explained why. Care to post your own answer then?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good point. It's been a while since I used it on multiple fields. Thanks.

Comment: Is it reasonable to edit your answer and then make that kind of comment? Anyway, your new solution works just as well without the SUM bit. That's my point.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the SUM function is used to sum over all rows, so `SUM(c1 + c2 + c3) AS table_total` is **not** the same as `(c1 + c2 + c3) AS row_total`.